# How to ensure that beanManager.getReference always creates a new object on every call?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, javabeans, cdi

How to ensure that

```
<class> classInstance = (class)beanManager.getReference(bean, 
      bean.getBeanClass(), beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean));
```

Always creates a new object on every call?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CDI you should annotate your bean class with @RequestScoped.

for example:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SomeBean{
...
}
```

[Read more here](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/cdi-request-scope/README.html)

Comment: but as per the link below i can see that beanManager#getReference will give a new instance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048410/canonical-way-to-obtain-cdi-managed-bean-instance-beanmanagergetreference-vs?answertab=active#tab-top